# Forms sends value of the first form in the table, not that of the current form

Tags: flask, jinja2, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

i have this app to buy and sell stocks

[image]

I generate the `Buy` buttons with Jinja (and bootstrap modal):

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#buy">Buy</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="buy" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="buy" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="symbol" value="{{ stock.symbol }}">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="buy-{{ stock.symbol }}">Buy</label>
            <input type="number" name="shares" id="buy-{{ stock.symbol }}" class="form-control" required>
          </div>
          
          <input type="hidden" name="transaction_type" value="buy">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buy</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see that each buy button is in a separate form, so it is supposed to submit a form with its own `symbol`, i.e. TSLA for the first form, NFLX for the second form.

But no, right now, it works like this: any buy buttons I click, it sends a request for the first symbol in the table (TSLA in this case) (I check the request in the network tab).

Any idea why?

Comment: It might help to see some examples of rendered HTML. Are the hidden inputs being populated correctly, for example?

Comment: hi, i figured it out. the id of the modal is not unique, so any button links back to the first modal. if people downvote this, i probably would delete it

Comment: If you're not going to delete, be sure to accept your answer to resolve this question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The generated id for each modal is not unique, so any button links back to the first modal.